# Shared binary format between iOS and Python

Tags: python, ios, binary

Is there a shared binary format between iOS and Python? I found binary property lists.

I have a list of `UIBeziarPath`s in an array that I want to be able to send to Python. I am just looking for something that will very efficiently be able to do that. I looked into the text based formats like JSON except they seem less efficient than a binary format for this purpose.

Comment: JSON *might* be less efficient, depending on the contents of your data. If the Bézier control points are all long decimal numbers — `[[3.52134223,-1.138012382],[0.847120941,0.001883412]]` — then a binary format will win, but if they are integers — `[[234,28],[-202,0]]` — then you might find that JSON is more compact than binary formats, which tend to use eight bytes plus overhead to store reals. If bandwidth is a major concern, you'll probably end up having to roll your own compression that exploits the patterns of data present in you curves (e.g., delta-compress adjacent control points).

Comment: In fact, if you use BERT (another binary format that I forgot to mention earlier), reals are actually encoded using their ASCII decimal representation, so there is no encoding-size advantage at all.

Comment: I'm very new to this, how exactly do you implement BERT format in ios?

Comment: Your best best is [libbert](https://github.com/ruediger/libbert), a C++ BERT codec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no formats specifically designed for iOS/Python. There are numerous data interchange formats you *could* use, including protocol buffers, BSON, ASN.1 (if you're that way inclined) and even a range of binary XML serialisation formats.

OTOH, I would strongly favour JSON (a textual format) unless bandwidth is exceptionally tight.

**EDIT:** I was awfully remiss not to mention another strong contender for binary transmission: BERT. I would favour BERT over any other binary format, but note my comments to the original question regarding encoding size.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a `struct` standard module that allows easy manipulation of simple binary formats with conversion to python types (`struct.unpack`) or in the opposite direction (`struct.pack`).